# How to use powershell function parameters

Tags: function, powershell

This a very newbie powershell question, but I couldn't find what's wrong in my little script, I appreciate if anyone can help on this. So, my function is as basic as :

```
cls
function Matchstring  ($source, $compare) {

write-host -ForegroundColor Green ("Comparing " + $compare +' and '+ $source)
}

Matchstring('Test1', 'Test2')
```

But the result I get is **Comparing  and Test1 Test2**  instead of  **Comparing Test1 and Test2**

Comment: Function parameters in calls are space separated, not comma separated like in function definition.

Comment: This is completley detailed in the Powershell Help files.  [about_Parameters - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters)   ---  [about_Parameter_Sets - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameter_sets). This [Matchstring('Test1', 'Test2')] is wrong. You cannot use comas or those parens. It's this [Matchstring -source 'Source' -compare 'Compare']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No comma and no parenthesis in the call line.

```
Matchstring 'Test1' 'Test2'
```